# Blend tikz gradient right color with background

Tags: tikz-pgf, text, box, gradient

I am trying to make a gradient box with text with the right color completely blend with the background. Here is my document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[inner xsep=2mm,text width=5cm,left color=red,right color=white]
      {\parbox[t]{\textwidth}{\color{white}\sffamily\bfseries A}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result I got is this:

[image: gradient1]

I want the border at the right to be gone and the right color to completely blend with the background like this:

[image: gradient2]

I tried fade with transparency from [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/156394/151425) but the result is the same.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: If available, opaque (transparent) would be the better choice. If available, you'd need to shift the fading point more to the left. See drawing programs, or even Excel.

Comment: Can you give an example how to shift the fading point to the left?

Answer (score 0):

Use `\usepgflibrary{shadings}`, and put the `middle color` option last. Add text, e.g. by putting a node to anchor `west`.

**P.S.** See also e.g. [Tikz gradient with 3 or more colors using pgfdeclarehorizontalshading](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/646692/tikz-gradient-with-3-or-more-colors-using-pgfdeclarehorizontalshading)

[image: gradient]

```
\documentclass[10pt, border=3mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepgflibrary{shadings}

% see pgf manual, ch. 69 Shadings Library

\begin{document}

    \tikz \draw[left color=red, right color=white, middle color=red!5]
    (0,0) rectangle (2,1);% middle must be last

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you post the example without the black border and with text?

Comment: Kindly please check the manual(s) at https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf .